# Inserta de a dos registros

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo un inconveniente, al agregar un registro lo guarda por duplicado de la siguiente manera:

```
actualPorcentaje 10 | marcaid 0
actualPorcentaje 0  | marcaid 4
```

Este formulario me permite actualizar los precios a través de un porcentaje, previo seleccionar una marca.

```
<form id="formProductos" 
      action="<?php echo base_url() ?> index.php/actualizacion/adicionar" method="post">

    <label for="">Porcentaje a actualizar</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Escriba el % de actualización" id="actualPorcentaje" name="actualPorcentaje"  />

</form> 

<?php

 echo '<a id="enviar" href="'.base_url().'index.php/actualizacion/adicionar/'.$marcaid.'"> Actualizar Precios</a>';  

?>


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#enviar").click(function(event){ 

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             data: $('#formProductos').serialize(),
             url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/actualizacion/adicionar",
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data)
             {
                 if(data.result == true){
                     $('.results').html(data);
                 }                          
                 else{                          
                     alert('Ocurrió un error al agregar un producto.');                         
                 }
             }
        });
    });
});
```

Función para insertar registros en model.php

```
function add($table,$data){
    $this->db->insert($table, $data);

    if ($this->db->affected_rows() == '1') 
    { 
        return TRUE; 
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Función para adicionar registros en controller.php

```
function adicionar(){ 
    $this->load->library('pagination'); 
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/actualizacion/gerenciar/'; 
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->actualizacion_model->count('actualprecios'); 
    $config['per_page'] = 10; 
    $config['next_link'] = 'Próxima'; 
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Anterior'; 
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination alternate"><ul>'; 
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>'; 
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>'; 
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>'; 
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li><a style="color: #2D335B"><b>'; 
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</b></a></li>'; 
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>'; 
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>'; 
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>'; 
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>'; 
    $config['first_link'] = 'Primeira'; 
    $config['last_link'] = 'Última'; 
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>'; 
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>'; 
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>'; 
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>'; 

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);      
    $this->data['results'] = $this->actualizacion_model->get('actualprecios','idActualizacion, actualPorcentaje,actualFecha','',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3)); 

    $this->load->library('form_validation'); 
    $this->data['custom_error'] = '';  

    $marcaid = $this->uri->segment(3); 
    $this->data['productos'] = $this->actualizacion_model->getProductosById($marcaid); 

    $productos = $this->data['productos'];                                             
    $dataInicial = date("Y").'-'.date("m").'-'.date("d"); 
    $usuario = $this->session->userdata('logado'); 
    $actualPorcentaje = $this->input->post('actualPorcentaje'); 

    $data = array(                 
        'actualPorcentaje' => $actualPorcentaje , 
        'actualFecha' => $dataInicial, 
        'marcaid' => $marcaid, 
        'usuarioid' => $usuario,  
    ); 

    if ( is_numeric($id = $this->actualizacion_model->add('actualprecios', $data, true)) ) { 

        foreach ($productos as $p) { 
            $idProdutos = $p->idProdutos;         
            $precoVenda = $p->precoVenda; 
            $precioAnterior = $p->precoVenda; 
            $precoVenda = $precoVenda *(1 + $actualPorcentaje / 100); 
            $sql = "UPDATE produtos set precioAnterior = ?, precoVenda = ? WHERE idProdutos = ?"; 
            $this->db->query($sql, array($precioAnterior, $precoVenda, $idProdutos)); 
        } 
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success','El registro de Actualización de Precios se agregó correctamente!!!'); 
        redirect(base_url().'index.php/actualizacion/gerenciar/');      

    } else { 
        $this->data['custom_error'] = '<div class="form_error"><p>An Error Occured.</p></div>'; 
    }         
    $this->data['view'] = 'actualizacionp/actualizacion'; 
    $this->load->view('tema/topo', $this->data); 
}
```

Comment: gracias Mariano! no podía editarlo como correspondía e intenté pegar imágenes pero aun no tengo el puntaje suficiente.

Answer (score 1):

Debes enviar todo en una sola petición.

Sugiero:

```
<a href="#" id="enviar">Actualizar precios</a>
```

Luego manejar todo con javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#enviar").click(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); // para prevenir la recarga de página
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: $('#formProductos').serialize(),
      url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/actualizacion/adicionar/<?php echo $marcaid ?>",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        if(data.result == true){
          $('.results').html(data);
        } else {                          
          alert('Ocurrió un error al agregar un producto.');                         
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas enviando la petición 2 veces.
Intenta cambiar

```
<?php
   echo '<a id="enviar" href="'.base_url().'index.php/actualizacion/adicionar/'.$marcaid.'"> Actualizar Precios</a>';  
?>
```

con

```
<?php
   echo '<a id="enviar" href="#"> Actualizar Precios</a>';  
?>
```

Y por otro lado en tu funcion de JS.
En la primer linea agregar.

```
event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: gracias por responder Juan! probé con los cambios que indicaste pero no guarda $marcaid, solo pasa $actualPorcentaje

Answer (score 0):

Bien, esto envía "marcaid"

```
<a id="enviar" href="'.base_url().'index.php/actualizacion/adicionar/'.$marcaid.'"> Actualizar Precios</a>';
```

y esto envía "actualPorcentaje"

```
data: $('#formProductos').serialize(),

url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/actualizacion/adicionar",
```

intenté enviar de diferentes formas las  2 variables desde ajax pero quizás no lo hice bien

También probé agregando esto al formulario pensando que data: $('#formProductos').serialize(), abarcaría el envío de ambas variables

```
<input type="text" id="marcaid" name="marcaid" value="<?php echo $marcaid; ?>" />
```

pero no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas enviando 2 peticiones:

La primera es esta:

```
<a id="enviar" href="'.base_url().'index.php/actualizacion/adicionar/'.$marcaid.'"> Actualizar Precios</a>';
```

Y la segunda es el evento al dar clic al link:

```
$("#enviar").click(function(event){ 
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             data: $('#formProductos').serialize(),
             url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/actualizacion/adicionar",
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data)
             {
                 if(data.result == true){
                     $('.results').html(data);
                 }                          
                 else{                          
                     alert('Ocurrió un error al agregar un producto.');                         
                 }
             }
        });
    });
```

Lo que sugiero es quitar el href del link y dejarlo asi:

```
<a id="enviar" href="#"> Actualizar Precios</a>';
```

Y el evento asi:

```
$("#enviar").click(function(event){ 
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             data: $('#formProductos').serialize(),
             url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/actualizacion/adicionar/<?php echo $marcaid; ?>",
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(data)
             {
                 if(data.result == true){
                     $('.results').html(data);
                 }                          
                 else{                          
                     alert('Ocurrió un error al agregar un producto.');                         
                 }
             }
        });
    });
```

Espero te sea de ayuda